# Upload node modules to nexus

Tags: npm, nexus, node-modules

I would like to create a private npm repo on our nexus.
So i guess i need to take the current node_modules folder on my machine and put it in Nexus, right?
I cant proxy npm, because on our jenkins machine we don't have internet access.

So how do i put all my node modules (lots of folders) onto Nexus?
and in what structure and format?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/DarthHater/nexus-repository-import-scripts for uploading a lot of files into NXRM3.

If that doesn't work for you, likely you can modify that script for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, i already tried this kind of concept, going over all of the node_modules folders and npm publish each of them.
But it doesn't work, npm install on the build server is failing because of recursive dependencies

Comment: Yep, you'll have to push up the dependancies too.

Comment: So i have to "npm install" each of the dependancies and their dependancies and so on..? that's insane

Comment: @BennyAfriat It's really not designed for use without the internet IMO.  You'd have this same problem with any internetless solution with internet dependancies I think.

Comment: But from searching google for "offline" jenkins machines i do see it's a valid scenario

Comment: @BennyAfriat It may be my ignorance, but I suspect folks that do that do not have online dependancies.  You could definitely easily do this if you didn't.